# Faster way to solve android lock valid patterns

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, compile, code-review

With the password grid shown in the Android home screen, how many valid passwords are possible?

[image]
The rules for creating a pattern is as follows.

- We must use four nodes or more to make a pattern at least.
- Once a node is visited, then the node can't be visited anymore.
- You can start at any node.
- A pattern has to be connected.
- Cycle is not allowed.

Read more, [How Many Different Unlock Patterns Could You Create](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9dXrKUCfO0)?

I have code that worked, one way using pattern-matching, another way using string-manipulation, they are not efficient, takes about 10 seconds. The [Python version](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XySs5nNnpJ/) takes about 1 second.

As far as I know, both of them does not support `Compile`. Is there a more efficient way?

```
(* pattern-matching version *)

list={{1,3},{3,1},{4,6},{6,4},{7,9},{9,7},{1,7},{7,1},{2,8},{8,2},{3,9},{9,3},{1,9},{9,1},
  {3,7},{7,3}};

ps=Function[{a,b},{___,(a+b)/2,___,a,b,___}|Except[{___,a,b,___}]] @@@ list;

Fold[Cases, Permutations[Range[9],{4,9}], ps]//Length//AbsoluteTiming

(* Output: {8.69702, 389112} *)
(*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*)


(*string-manipulation version*)

AbsoluteTiming[
 invalidList = {{"13","2"}, {"31","2"}, {"46","5"}, {"64","5"}, {"79","8"}, {"97", "8"}, 
  {"17","4"}, {"71","4"}, {"28","5"}, {"82","5"}, {"39","6"}, {"93","6"}, {"19","5"}, 
  {"91","5"}, {"37","5"}, {"73","5"}} ;

 count = 0;
 Do[
  Catch[
   Do[
    If[StringContainsQ[stri, First@i] && 
      StringFreeQ[StringTake[stri, StringPosition[stri, First@i][[1, 1]]], Last@i],
        Throw[0]];,
    {i, invalidList}]; count++]

  , {stri, 
   StringJoin /@ Permutations[Characters@"123456789", {4, 9}]}];
 count
 ]

(* Output: {12.8075, 389112} *)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, because I am not using Android, what are the valid configurations? Can you state it in words?

Comment: @yarchik Updated.

Comment: Related on Stackoverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979963/395258](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6979963/395258)

Comment: Sorry for disturbing, but I still do not understand. 1) What does it mean that "A pattern has to be connected."? 2)What is the difference between the point 2 "Once a node is visited, then the node can't be visited anymore." and the point 5 "Cycle is not allowed."? 3) If in your example 1, you make a stop at 2, would it be a valid pattern or not?

Comment: @yarchik https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9dXrKUCfO0, this link may be useful.

Comment: My understanding is that the number 389112 is what you get when you also take into account that going through a number (e.g. 1 to 9 passes through 5) is valid if that number has already been used. This is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, rules here require a question should be self-explanatory. That is, understandable without external links. They may not be available later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to speed up your existing code even without compilation. The idea is to count not all configurations, but rather the *topologically different* ones.

There are 3 topologically distinct possibilities to start a path

1. Corner: 1, 3, 7, 9
2. Edge:   2, 4, 6, 8
3. Center: 5

Thus, it is sufficient to count the number of paths starting from 1 (`n[1]`), starting from 2 (`n[2]`) and starting from 5 (`n[5]`). The total number of configurations is given by the sum weighted with symmetry factors.

I keep your definitions of `list` and `ps` and perform timing of each part of the algorithm.

```
(x=Permutations[Range[9],{4,9}];)//AbsoluteTiming
Out[3]= {0.145363,Null}

(y[1]=Cases[x,{1,___}];
 y[2]=Cases[x,{2,___}];
 y[5]=Cases[x,{5,___}];)//AbsoluteTiming
Out[4]= {0.3311,Null}

Fold[Cases,x,ps]//Length//AbsoluteTiming
Out[5]= {13.6685,389112}

(n[1]=Fold[Cases,y[1],ps]//Length)//AbsoluteTiming
(n[2]=Fold[Cases,y[2],ps]//Length)//AbsoluteTiming
(n[5]=Fold[Cases,y[5],ps]//Length)//AbsoluteTiming

Out[6]= {1.40567,38042}
Out[7]= {1.60751,43176}
Out[8]= {1.71645,64240}

4n[1]+4n[2]+n[5]
Out[9]= 389112
```

### Discussion

The results of the timing with respect to the original algorithm are as follows:

1. Generation of all configurations 1%.
2. Selection of the corner, edge and center classes 2%.
3. Brute-force selection of the valid configurations 99%.
4. Selection of valid paths starting at the corner 10%, the edge 12%, and the center 12%.

Even with this simplest idea the achieved time saving is **65%.** This approach can be systematically extended further depending on the time one wants to invest in the topological analysis.

### Challenge

This problem can be easily generalized to any $n\times n$ grid. However, only for $3\times 3$ and $4\times 4$ the solution is known. Can someone compute the $5\times 5$ number ?

Answer (score 4):

In the same manner as [yarchik](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/9469/yarchik)'s answer, but leveraging more symmetries.

Also using `ps` as defined in the question.

```
t = {2, 6};
u = {3, 6, 9};

eightfoldStarts = Thread /@
    {{1, t}, {1, 5, {2, 3, 6}}, {1, 5, 9, t},
     {2, u}, {2, 5, u}, {2, 5, 8, u},
     {5, 1, t}, {5, 1, 9, t}, {5, 2, u}, {5, 2, 8, u}} // Catenate;

finish[s : {__Integer}] :=
  Join[s, #] & /@ Permutations[Complement[Range@9, s], {4 - Length@s, 9}];

filter[s : {__Integer}] := Fold[Cases, finish@s, ps]

8 Total[Length@*filter /@ eightfoldStarts] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.15843, 389112}

Answer (score 3):

There is a more concise and slightly faster pattern matching solution:

```
impossible = {{1, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 6}, {6, 4}, {7, 9}, {9, 7}, {1, 
   7}, {7, 1}, {2, 8}, {8, 2}, {3, 9}, {9, 3}, {1, 9}, {9, 1}, {3, 
   7}, {7, 3}};
possible = Permutations[Range[9], {4, 9}];

Count[possible, {___, PatternSequence @@@ Alternatives @@ impossible, ___}];
```

This takes around 7.22 seconds on my machine, against 11.24 seconds for your pattern matching solution. (By the way, you should use `RepeatedTiming`, not `AbsoluteTiming`, for more accurate timing results!)

**Edit 1**: Ah, `OrdlessPatternSequence` is a thing.

```
Count[possible,
  {___, OrderlessPatternSequence @@@ 
    Alternatives @@ {{1, 3}, {4, 6}, {7, 9}, {1, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 
       9}, {1, 9}, {3, 7}}, ___}
  ]
```

Takes 5.24 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Thanks for help, but your answer given `845944`, not `389112`.

Comment: Aha, strange. Either way it would be counting the occurrences of invalid lock patterns, rather than valid ones...

Comment: I agree that this is the solution to the problem as it is currently stated. I solved it using a graph approach, which is super fast, but it also says that there are 139880 valid patterns rather than 389112. I wrote a comment to the question about where the number 389112 comes from.