# Permutation Combinations Mobile Pattern Codes

Tags: mathematical-optimization, string-manipulation, permutation

Please help write codes to determine 4 to 6 dot patterns. I am stuck after permutations input. It would really help if one could write direct so I could copy paste code to determine list of 4 to 6 dot patterns. Pl refer article.

https://www.guokr.com/article/49408/
[image: I have uploaded jpeg of the error I am facing]
Code error at =Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@
Partition[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 3, 7}, 2], 1]

Comment: As it is now posed, this question isn't well suited for this site. It essentially amounts to asking for a free coding service to implement a vaguely specified program. It will very likely be closed.

Comment: Related [faster-way-to-solve-android-lock-valid-patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208785/faster-way-to-solve-android-lock-valid-patterns)

Comment: Complicated Mathematica expressions cannot be interpreted as natural language; hence, `(no interpretation available)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The articles says it all:

```
all4to6 = Permutations[Range[9], {4, 6}]; (*possible permut. with 4..6 elements*)
invalseg = 
  Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ 
    Partition[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 3, 7}, 2], 1];(*invalid segments*)
inval = {Alternatives @@ 
    Apply[PatternSequence[Except[(#1 + #2)/2] ..., #1, #2] &, 
     invalseg, {1}], ___};(*invalid pattern*)
valid = DeleteCases[all4to6, inval];(*valid permut.*)
sorted = Sort[valid]; 
Length[sorted]  (*34792*)
{all4, all5, all6} = Split[sorted, Length[#1] == Length[#2] &] (*split 4,5,6 elements*)
Length /@ {all4, all5, all6}
(*{1624, 7152, 26016}*)
```

Comment: I am putting =Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ Partition[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 3, 7}, 2], 1] but there is no output

Comment: That is because I put a semicolon at the end that will suppress any output.

Comment: Sir. I am a noob. Pl help by simplifying. It says no interpretation available. I am copying your answer as it is.

Comment: Please start a new kernel. Then copy / paste my input. Then you should get the output: 34797,  a large list with permutations and {1624, 7152, 26016}. The first number is the total number of permutations and the numbers in the last list are the numbers of permutations with 4, 5 and 5 elements.

Comment: I am stuck at invalseg. I paste as it is =Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ 
    Partition[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 3, 7}, 2], 1] I am using 12.1 version

Comment: Pl advice what am I doing wrong. It would be really helpful.

Comment: @VIJIT - the code in this answer executes successfully with v12.1 Unless you edit your question with the complete code that you are using we cannot tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question and also added image of error. Pl help.

Comment: @VIJIT - The code is `invalseg = Flatten[{#, Reverse@#} & /@ Partition[{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 1, 9, 3, 7}, 2], 1];` By leaving off the variable and starting an expression with `=` you are asking for the expression to be interpreted as **natural language input** -- which it isn't. When an attempt is made to interpret it as natural language, there is `(no interpretation available)` Copy and paste the complete answer above into a fresh notebook.